# How to post <input> value to database

Tags: php, html, sql

My `<input>` values does not get post to my database when I click the submit button. I am unable to find the error. Please help.

```
 <?php
    echo "<form action=Display.php method=post>";
    echo "<td>" . $fiberexcel['Engineer9'] ." </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $fiberexcel['AM10'] ." </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=date name=A12 value=" . $fiberexcel['Quotation11'] ." </td>";

    $A6 = date("Y-m-d");
    $ExpectDateQuotation12 = strtotime($ReqDate4."+ 10 weekday");
    echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d",$ExpectDateQuotation12) . "</td>";
    $ExpectDateQuotation12 = date("Y-m-d",$ExpectDateQuotation12);
    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE `fiberexcel` SET `ExpectDateQuotation12` =
    '$ExpectDateQuotation12' WHERE `fiberexcel`.`SiteID0` = '$A1';";
    mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateQuery);

    echo "<td>" . "<input type=date name=A14 value=" . $fiberexcel['ApprovalJFSRequest13'] ." </td>";
    ?>

    echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" .$fiberexcel['SiteID0'] ." </td>";
    //echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update>". "</td>";
    echo "</form>";
```

This is my update button post function:

```
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
       $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE `fiber`.`fiberexcel` SET Quotation11='$_POST[A12]' ,  ApprovalJFSRequest13='$_POST[A14]' WHERE `fiberexcel`.`SiteID0`='$_POST[hidden]'";

       mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateQuery);
    };
```

Comment: Don't put raw post data into sql statements like `"UPDATE \`fiber\`.\`fiberexcel\` SET Quotation11='$_POST[A12]' ,  ApprovalJFSRequest13='$_POST[A14]' WHERE \`fiberexcel\`.\`SiteID0\`='$_POST[hidden]'"`. This is prone to sql injection.

Comment: Even If I add this post function also not posting to database  "UPDATE fiberexcel SET Quotation11='$_POST[A12]' , ApprovalJFSRequest13='$_POST[A14]' WHERE fiberexcel.SiteID0='$_POST[hidden]'"`.

Comment: and dont use `\`` in PHP, use `'` instead. The Querys PHPMyAdmin gives you do not work in PHP

Comment: Ok. I changed ` into ' Still not working :(

Comment: @JRsz Which backticks are you referring to in this script? Php can execute backtick column and table names.

Comment: @Rasclatt I want to update my <input> dates/values to database. The calculation got updated in the database & displayed in the page. That works. But my input values doesn't work. Can you help?

Comment: Do `print_r($_POST);` at the top and submit the form. See if you are getting the values you expect.

Comment: print_r($_POST); not working but no errors also

Comment: You can not use `td` without `table>tr`

Comment: @Rasclatt The back ticks in the query. My MySQL Server never accepted these if they originated from a PHP script...

Comment: @JRsz that is interesting, I use backticks for table and column names across a lot of different hosting on all kinds of projects and have never had any issue (I use PDO primarily on Linux-based servers).

Comment: Hm, I can only use single and double straight things, ' and " I use the procedural way also on a linux machine, maybe this makes the difference...

Comment: Anyway.. Thanks guys. Somehow I rectified :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check your HTML output in browser.

I have noticed some issues in your code

-you have missed quotes for every attribute values
    ex:
    echo "";

wolud be like
    echo "";

- also there is an error in your HTML code,
  ex: 
  echo "" . "";
  here your have missed to close the input tag,

your code wold be like below,

```
<?php
echo "<form action='Display.php' method='post'>";

echo "<td>" . $fiberexcel['Engineer9'] ." </td>";
echo "<td>" . $fiberexcel['AM10'] ." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='date' name='A12' value='" . $fiberexcel['Quotation11'] ."'></td>";

$A6 = date("Y-m-d");
$ExpectDateQuotation12 = strtotime($ReqDate4."+ 10 weekday");
echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d",$ExpectDateQuotation12) . "</td>";
$ExpectDateQuotation12 = date("Y-m-d",$ExpectDateQuotation12);
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE `fiberexcel` SET `ExpectDateQuotation12` =
'$ExpectDateQuotation12' WHERE `fiberexcel`.`SiteID0` = '$A1';";
mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateQuery);

echo "<td>" . "<input type='date' name='A14' value='" . $fiberexcel['ApprovalJFSRequest13'] ."'> </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='" .$fiberexcel['SiteID0'] ."'> </td>";
//echo "</tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='update' value='update'>". "</td>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Comment: Can you please share HTML source what you having in your browser, and also the table strecture

Comment: Yeah. Sure. @mukesh <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:11px; font-family:verdana;" >
<tr>  
<!--1--><th>Site ID</th>
<!--2--><th>Site Name</th>
<!--3--><th>Site Address</th>
<th>Project Type</th>
<th>Implementation Requested Date </th>
<th>Target Completion Date</th>
<th>Vendor</th>
<th>ESR No</th> 
<th>Contact Details</th>
<th>Engineer</th>
<th>Account Manager</th>
<th>Sent to Contractors for Quotation</th>
<th>Expected Date</th>
<th>SO Approval for JFS Requested</th>
</tr> //Like wise there are 67 colums in the table

Comment: @Sugs Thank you, But I didn't find the form in your html

Comment: Form I have given in php. echo "<form action=Display.php method=post>"; It is in the code above

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax error in your code. Please check the php close tag and input close tag. Try this..

```
<?php
echo "<form action='Display.php' method='post'>";
echo "<td>" . $fiberexcel['Engineer9'] ." </td>";
echo "<td>" . $fiberexcel['AM10'] ." </td>";
echo "<td><input type='date' name='A12' value=" . $fiberexcel['Quotation11'] ."/></td>";

$A6 = date("Y-m-d");
$ExpectDateQuotation12 = strtotime($ReqDate4."+ 10 weekday");
echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d",$ExpectDateQuotation12) . "</td>";
$ExpectDateQuotation12 = date("Y-m-d",$ExpectDateQuotation12);
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE `fiberexcel` SET `ExpectDateQuotation12` =
'$ExpectDateQuotation12' WHERE `fiberexcel`.`SiteID0` = '$A1';";
mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateQuery);

echo "<td><input type='date' name='A14' value=" . $fiberexcel['ApprovalJFSRequest13'] ." /></td>";


echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='hidden' value=" .$fiberexcel['SiteID0'] ." /></td>";
//echo "</tr>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='update' value='update'></td>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

Comment: Syntax error. done. Stil it doesn't get stored in the database

Comment: Try by putting quotes (') inside your input tag for type and name. I have edited my code. please check.

Comment: Yes. I added (') and tried. Its not showing any error. At the same time no result :(

Comment: Omg!! Can you please share the screenshot to see what result you got